# Overloading virtual functions in two different interfaces

Tags: c++, interface, overloading

I have an issue where I have an interface that has parts that make sense as templated, and parts that make sense as not-templated.  I'm in the middle of a refactor where I'm splitting that out into two different interfaces where the more specific (the templated one) inherits from the other one.  E.g., say I have an interface `IArray`, this would contain functions like `Size()` since it doesn't care about the data type.  But I'd have another interface `ITArray<DataType>` that would have something like `DataType GetElement(...)`.  (This is just for illustration, don't yell at me to use std::vector).  The reason I'm doing this refactor is that there are a lot of consumers of the non-templated interface and they'd like to not have to write templated functions that accept a templated interface if they don't need the templated type (generally `extern "C"` stuff)

The problem is that I have overloaded functions that appear in both interfaces, but for some reason I can't resolve the base class functions.  Here's a simple example that I put together that's not compiling in MSVC:

```
#include <iostream>

class IA
{
public:
        virtual void X()=0;
};

template <class DataType>
class ITA : public IA
{
public:
        //If I uncomment this line, it all works!
        //virtual void X()=0;
        virtual void X(DataType d)=0;
};

template <class DataType>
class A : public ITA<DataType>
{
public:
    void X()
    {
        std::cout << "In X" << std::endl;
    }

    void X(DataType d)
    {
        std::cout << "In X, d=" << d << std::endl;
    }
};

template <class DataType>
void DoSomething(ITA<DataType>& I, DataType d)
{
    I.X(); //MSVC can't resolve this since it's in IA, not ITA
    I.X(d);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    A<int> I;
    DoSomething(I,10);
}
```

Is there some way that I can make IA's functions appear in ITA<> without manually putting them there?  I see a maintenance nightmare ahead of me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding a `using` directive? `IA::X` is a hidden by `A::X`.

```
class A : ...
{
public:
    using IA::X;
    virtual void X(DataType d) = 0; 
};
```

Comment: Oh, that works.  Now is there a way to "import" all of IA's functions, say I had X, Y, and Z to bring over.  Automatically, that is, I'd rather not have to do using IA::X, using IA::Y, using IA::Z.

Comment: If `A` wants to overload functions that exist in `IA`, then `A` must declare which methods it is importing rather than hiding.

Comment: It is the same, you have to say you are "using" the methods you're hiding, all others are directly available!